# What is the ultimate meaning of resistance in Money Heist?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, money-heist

After watching *La Casa De Papel* / *Money Heist*, I still do not fully understand the intent or message behind the repeated theme of resistance in the show. How are the heists performed by the gang any different from any other heist performed in real life aside from the level of planning, the scale of what is being stolen, lack of killing, and who is being robbed?

Comment: possibly the robberies are acts of reistance against society's oppressive rules requiring money to survive and requiring honest work to earn money, or something like that.